Cloud Run Custom Domain GTM
Good Day.
In search of direction...GTM / Cloud Run

I've installed a new property with a web-container and server-container
I've setup Cloud Run to accept a custom
subdomain.

When my website's code uses src=googletagmanager.com everything flows through to GA4.
When I change the src to my custom domain -- nothing.
However, when I run the Health Check, it returns ok.  What am I missing? Thanks.
My server-side GTM has a client type=GA4 (web) with Activation Criteria: Default GA4 paths and Cookies and ClientID Server Managed
My web-side GTM tag is Google Tag with Tag ID = <my G4 stream ID> and configuration parameter: server_container_url = <my custom domain>
